# scikit-surprise lib recommends only the products user has already bought

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

I am trying to use scikit-surprise library (KKN Basic) to get recommendations using Python for a retail company. I do not want to recommend products that have been already bought/rated once by the user. The cosine similarity results from KNNBasic show only the case where rui>0 and est>1. How can I get recommendation for user A, that user A has not already rated?

Link to Jupyter notebook I used :https://www.dropbox.com/s/y7vf74dyar6d70u/Code.ipynb?dl=0
Link to sample dataset of 1000 users : https://www.dropbox.com/s/rqj9zazfwew2280/userItemData.csv?dl=0

Comment: Do you have code and date to reproduce ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan Sorry I did not share the link to code or dataset earlier, have updated now. The code is a jupyter notebook.